# SQL - grouping and summarizing in single record

Tags: sql

I have a table that consists of orderlines that looks like this.

```
| product_id |  amount |  shop_id |
|------------|---------|----------|
|       1234 |       1 |  a       |
|       1234 |       2 |  b       |
|       1234 |       3 |  c       |
|       1234 |       2 |  a       |
|       1234 |       2 |  b       |
|       2222 |       1 |  a       |
|       2222 |       4 |  b       |
```

The result I'm looking for is a single record that sums up the total amount in the Amount column and in addition columns with the Amount for each of the shop_id's
So based on the data above, the result should be like this:

```
| product_id |  amount total |  amount shop_id a |  amount shop_id b |  amount shop_id c |
|------------|---------------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|       1234 |            10 |                 3 |                 4 |                 3 |
|       2222 |             5 |                 1 |                 4 |                 0 |
```

Is this possible to achieve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: MySQL - thanks, I'll remember that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT product_id,
       SUM(amount) as amount_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN shop_id = 'a' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as amount_shop_id_a,
       SUM(CASE WHEN shop_id = 'b' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as amount_shop_id_b,
       SUM(CASE WHEN shop_id = 'c' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as amount_shop_id_c
FROM table t
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for